# read optional url parameters

Tags: javascript, url, routes, sapui5

I want to catch an optional url parameter in my sapui5 application.

Manifest:

```
            "routes": [
            {
                "pattern": "page_1:query:",
                "name": "page_1",
                "target": [
                    "page_1"
                ]
            }]
```

Controller:

```
    handleRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
        var oArgs, oView, oQuery;
        oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments"); // undefined
        console.log(oEvent.mParameters);
```

**Testcases**

according to the Testcases
[PatternMatching](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.PatternMatching/preview)

- URLPattern :query:
- manifest pattern:query:
- would match: {"query":"test=123123,bla=123213"}

**URLs:**

/webapp/index.html?test=123

*has no value*: oEvent.mParameters.data.hash:  ""

/webapp/index.html?#/query=123

*has value*: oEvent.mParameters.data.hash:  query="123"

- why do I have to add  #/ ?
- And how can I avoid adding #/ ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are failing when understanding the UI5 Routing concept. You should not understand it as a GET request. The parameters you can pass in the hash route are not GET parameters.

So first, you should understand the parts of a URL, in this case we can say something like this:

```
<host>:<port>?myGetParam1=value1&myGetParam2=value2#/My/Navigation/Pattern/ParamValue1/ParamValue2`
```

From the `?` to the `#` you have the parameters for the GET request. They go to the server side.
From the `#` to the end you have your hash route. Used in the client side.

if you define in the manifest the pattern as

```
 /My/Navigation/Pattern/{ParamValue1}/:ParamValue2:
```

then the following examples will work

**#/My/Navigation/Pattern/3** --> It passes 3 as the mandatory *paramValue1* and nothing for the optional *paramValue2*

**#/My/Navigation/Pattern/3/2** --> It passes 3 as the mandatory *paramValue1* and 2 as the optional *paramValue2*

However if you try

**#/My/Navigation/Pattern/**

it will fail, because you has set the *paramValue1* as mandatory

To get those paramerters, define an event handler in your controller for the "RouteMatched" event. The parameters will be in the "arguments" of the event object. Clearly explained [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef).

I recomend you to go through [this tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d). It is one of the best tutorials in the UI5 demokit.